# Is there a way to write an Expression indicating a constructor parameter?

Tags: c#

Given the following type

```
class Foo 
{
    public string Bar { get; private set; }

    public Foo(string bar) 
    {
        Bar = bar;
    }
}
```

I can write

```
Expression<Func<Foo, string>> member = foo => foo.Bar;
```

and get an expression pointing to the member `Bar`.

Is there a similar way I could somehow write an expression that points to the constructor parameter `bar`?

---

<sup>My goals with this is to be able to indicate a constructor parameter in a way that is resilient to change; for example, when refactoring the constructor I might rename the parameter - this should carry over to the expression. If I remove it, the expression should cause  a build error, etc.</sup>

---

Update - further clarification of the usage I would like to enable:

Consider an extension method (doesn't really matter on what) called like this:

```
new object().DoSomething<Foo>(foo => foo.Bar);
```

If it's defined like this:

```
public static void DoSomething<T>(this object o, Expression<Func<T, object>> expr)
{
    // ...
}
```

I can access the property `Bar` and do various things with it inside the body of the extension method. For example, I could set its value given some input from somewhere else. A concrete use case is AutoMapper, which does something like this:

```
CreateMap<FooDto, Foo>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Bar, cfg => cfg.MapFrom(src => src.BarSrc));
```

The expression `dest => dest.Bar` indicates a property (on `Foo`) that we want to apply special configuration on, and `src => src.BarSrc` indicates a property (on `FooDto`) that we want to take the value from. In effect, when it's time to map a `FooDto` to a `Foo`, AutoMapper can extract the value of `BarSrc` from the source instance and set `Bar` on the destination instance to that value, using the two expressions.

What I want to be able to do, is to similarly say

```
CreateMap<FooDto, Foo>()
    .ForCtorParam(dest => /* what do I put here to indicate the bar ctor param? */,
        cfg => cfg.MapFrom(src => src.BarSrc));
```

(The current API is `.ForCtorParam("bar", ...)` which feels clunky to me.)

Comment: Think you are pointing to C# 6. In that case should edit your post to reflect that.

Comment: @Rahul What exactly is C# 6 about this post?

Comment: @Rahul: I don't care so much about C# version, but I do realize that C# 6 might be required to solve the problem. That's not inherent in the question, though, and solutions for earlier versions are very welcome too.

Comment: @juharr, exactly this `string Bar { get; }`

Comment: I'm not sure I understood why you need this. The constructor parameter is local to the constructor, and a refactoring tool would usually properly rename all usages, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Rahul Yeah, I missed that.

Comment: @TomasLycken, sole reason I made that comment is your property have only a getter without any backing field and in ctor you are trying to set it. In earlier version of C# this would throw a compiler error (Heard that in C# 6it's permitted, not sure though)

Comment: @Rahul: That's not important to the question, just a habit of the code style I'm currently working with. Could just as well have been `string Bar { get; private set; }`.

Comment: @DirkVollmar: One possible usecase is to improve the API of constructor mapping configurations in AutoMapper. Currently, you'd have to write `.ForCtorParam("bar", cfg => ...)`, but it would be nice to indicate that constructor parameter in some strongly typed, statically checked way.

Comment: @Rahul: I refactored away the C# 6 specifics, just to avoid any more confusion around this.

Comment: I just tried `Expression<Func<Foo>> example = () => new Foo(bar: "dummy");`, however the C# compiler complains that _An expression tree may not contain a named argument specification_ (CS0853).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not completely certain about your exact use case, but it seems that you are somehow somewhere relying on the name of the parameter in your code (which is not detected when you refactor).

If you want to avoid using the hard-coded name of the parameter, you can use `nameof` in C# 6.0:

```
public Foo(string bar)
{
    var nameOfBarParameter = nameof(bar);
    Bar = bar;
}
```

Note that this only works within the declaration scope of the parameter, i.e. the body of the constructor in this case.

If you need to access the name of the parameters outside of the constructor, I don't think there is a way using expressions. You can, of course, always use reflection to retrieve the related `ParameterInfo` and parameter name (but then you will depend on the parameter position not changing):

```
var ci = typeof(Foo).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string) });
var parameterName = ci.GetParameters()[0].Name;
```

Comment: This only works locally in the scope of the constructor, though; I'd like to be able to use this expression anywhere, not just inside the constructor. (See my comment on the question for a concrete use case.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this suits your need, but if you construct the expression tree:

```
Expression<Func<Foo>> expr = () => new Foo("dummy");
```

which makes use of `bar`, then:

```
ParameterInfo barParameter = ((NewExpression)(expr.Body)).Constructor.GetParameters()[0];
```

is a representation of the (zeroth) constructor parameter.